# General Relativity in Mathlib for Class Project

Tags: lean4, lean-mathlib

I'm interested in writing a general relativity folder for Lean 4, along the lines of Wald's book. Has this been done before? Since this is for a class project, I want to avoid using less elementary files from Mathlib as dependencies (e.g., it would be nice to adopt the list API, but the manifold API is too much). Is there anything I should be aware of before beginning this task?

Comment: Not to underestimate the size of the task?

Comment: How is it possible to develop general relativity without substantial differential geometry? Is there some easy system the physicists have figured out but didn't tell us mathematicians?

Comment: @AndrejBauer ... perhaps I'll work on something else.

Comment: @Trebor Is it not possible to write differential geometry into Mathlib?

Comment: Didn't you say in the question that you want to avoid depending on differential geometry in mathlib?